# Inner join on a partial column in Access

Tags: ms-access, join, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm attempting to join two tables in *MS Access 2010* where the join condition is `part of(A.col1) = B.col2`. I've not been able to figure out how to do this so far.

My two tables have these critical columns:

1. Table 1 has column `ICD9 Code-Description`* with values like:
   `842.00 - Sprain/strain, wrist`
   `924.11 - Contusion, knee`
2. Table 2 has column `Dx` with values like:
   `842`
   `924.11`

I have tried these two join criteria:

```
FROM Table1 
  INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Replace(LTrim(Replace(Left(ICD9Code-Description],
                           (InStr(1,[ICD9Code-Description]," "))-1),"0"," "))," ","0")  
                       = Table2.Dx
```

and

```
SELECT ICD9
  FROM Table2 INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT Replace(LTrim(Replace(Left([ICD9 Code-Description],
              (InStr(1,[ICD9 Code-Description]," "))-1),"0"," "))," ","0") AS ICD9
          FROM Table1)
       ON Diag.DX = ICD9
```

Neither of which Access likes.

I'd like to avoid pulling out the join criteria portion into its own column in `Table1` if at all possible.

**What would be the Access way of doing this?**

**Don't hate me for the column name. I didn't create it, I just have to support it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Val()` function *"Returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type."*  (See the *Val Function* help topic in Access' built-in help system.)

The "neat thing" for your situation is it reads characters from the string until it encounters a character which can't be part of a valid number.  But then it doesn't throw an error.  It just keeps the numeric characters it's already collected and ignores the rest.

Here's two of your examples in the Immediate window ...

```vb
? Val("842.00 - Sprain/strain, wrist")
 842 
? Val("924.11 - Contusion, knee")
 924.11
```

So `Val()` should make your `JOIN` much simpler, even though you would need to also apply it on the `Table2.Dx` strings ...

```sql
FROM
    Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Val(Table1.[ICD9Code-Description]) = Val(Table2.Dx)
```

Comment: Yes, sadly, `Table2.D` is in fact a text field. I just realized that. `Str(Val(ICD9Code-Description])) = Table2.Dx` fixes that, however now I'm getting no results instead of an error. I'll have to beat my head on it some more. The good news is that `Table2.Dx` has `Dx = 842` as a text string, not `Dx=842.00`, so the simple `Str()` fixes it. Thanks, though, `Val()` is an incredibly useful function and much easier to read that the prior disaster!

Comment: You sir, are a genius!! I'm not sure why that worked when `Str(val()) = ...` didn't, but I'll take it!  I'd also like to throttle the guy who designed this database for his crazy column names and moronic combination of data in columns, but, fortunately he's no longer working here. If he was, I'd probably be behind bars... :/

Comment: I'm glad it works, but it seems like too many run-time hoops to me.  :-)  If you're stuck with that table design, the only thing more I can offer is sympathy.  :-0

Comment: The opportunity to fix it is coming, but for now, I'm stuck, and your sympathy is gladly accepted...